# XSLT - select nodes that came after another node

Tags: xml, xslt, select, xquery

I'm trying to select all nodes that 1) come after a node with a particular property and 2) have a particular property themselves.  So if I had the following XML:

```
<node id="1"><child attr="valueOfInterest"/></node>
<node id="2"><child attr="boringValue"/></node>
...
<node id="3"><child attr="valueOfInterest"/></node>
<node id="4"><child attr="boringValue"/></node>
<node id="5"><child attr="boringValue"/></node>
<node id="6"><child attr="boringValue"/></node>
...
```

My XSLT traverses through each `node` tag.  At each `node`, I want it to select all previous `node`s that occurred since the most recent `node` that had a `child` whose `attr` was `valueOfInterest`.  So if I were at node #2, I would want an empty node set.  If I were at node #6, I would want to select node #'s 4 and 5.  I currently have the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="prev_vals"
    select="preceding-sibling::node/child[@attr = $someValueICareAbout]/@attr"/>
```

So this XSLT gets all preceding `attr` values that are a particular value.  How do I only get those preceding `attr` values that are in `node`s that come after the most recent `node` whose `child` has a particular `attr` value (i.e., "valueOfInterest")?  The `id` attribute on `node` tags is not guaranteed to be increasing, so we can't compare against that.

**Edit:**  I thought these might be of use:

```
<xsl:variable name="prev_children_of_interest"
    select="preceding-sibling::node/child[@attr != $someValueICareAbout]"/>
<xsl:variable name="mru_child_of_interest"
    select="$prev_children_of_interest[count($prev_children_of_interest)]"/>
```

So that's all previous `child` tags with `attr=valueOfInterest` and then the most recently used (closest to current node) `child` tag that has the attribute I'm looking for.  From `mru_child_of_interest` we can find the most recently used `parent` tag, but how do we then look for nodes that come after that tag?

Comment: This can be done using grouping. Can you use XSLT 2.0 (grouping features), or are you limited to 1.0?

Comment: `"$prev_children_of_interest[count($prev_children_of_interest)]"`: it looks like you are expecting the inner `$prev_children_of_interest` to be reevaluated in the context of each element in the outer `$prev_children_of_interest` node set. But in fact, the value of that variable is only evaluated at the point where the variable is defined. So this XPath expression is equivalent to `"$prev_children_of_interest"`.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution that uses the Kayessian formula for the intersection of two node-sets. :)

Comment: @Sarah Vessels: Was my answer useful or did you have any problems in using my solution?

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: your answer is useful and I appreciate the long reply.  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but here is some XSL 1.0 (additional `each-nodes` attributes are informational only):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="nodes">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node">
        <xsl:variable name="someValueICareAbout">valueOfInterest</xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="recentParticularNode"
            select="preceding-sibling::node[child/@attr = $someValueICareAbout][1]"/>

        <xsl:variable name="recentParticularNodePosition"
            select="count($recentParticularNode/preceding-sibling::node) + 1"/>

        <xsl:variable name="currentPosition" select="position()"/>

        <xsl:if test="child/@attr != $someValueICareAbout">
            <each-nodes id="{@id}" cp="{$currentPosition}" 
                    rpnp="{$recentParticularNodePosition}">
                <xsl:copy-of
                    select="../node[position() &gt; $recentParticularNodePosition
                    and position() &lt; $currentPosition]"/>
            </each-nodes>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nodes>
    <node id="1"><child attr="valueOfInterest"/></node>
    <node id="2"><child attr="boringValue2"/></node>
    <node id="3"><child attr="valueOfInterest"/></node>
    <node id="4"><child attr="boringValue4"/></node>
    <node id="5"><child attr="boringValue5"/></node>
    <node id="6"><child attr="boringValue6"/></node>
</nodes>
```

Result XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nodes>
   <each-nodes id="2" cp="2" rpnp="1"/>
   <each-nodes id="4" cp="4" rpnp="3"/>
   <each-nodes id="5" cp="5" rpnp="3">
      <node id="4">
         <child attr="boringValue4"/>
      </node>
   </each-nodes>
   <each-nodes id="6" cp="6" rpnp="3">
      <node id="4">
         <child attr="boringValue4"/>
      </node>
      <node id="5">
         <child attr="boringValue5"/>
      </node>
   </each-nodes>
</nodes>
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want the intersection of two sets. Set 1 is all the nodes after the last `valueOfInterest`. Set 2 is all the nodes before the current node that do not contain `valueOfInterest`. For XPath 1.0, the following will give you the intersection (reference found [here](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200811/post80020.html)).

```
$set1[count($set2|.)=count($set2)]
```

Given your input, the following XSL demonstrates the nodeset you are looking for

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:variable name="someValueICareAbout">valueOfInterest</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node[child/@attr='boringValue']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>

      <xsl:variable name="set1" select="preceding-sibling::node[child/@attr='valueOfInterest'][1]/following-sibling::node "/>

      <xsl:variable name="set2" select="preceding-sibling::node[child/@attr='boringValue']"/>

      <predecessors>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$set1[count($set2|.)=count($set2)]"/>
      </predecessors>

    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the output

```
<xml>
  <node id="1">
    <child attr="valueOfInterest"/>
  </node>
  <node id="2">
    <child attr="boringValue"/>
    <predecessors/>
  </node>
  <node id="3">
    <child attr="valueOfInterest"/>
  </node>
  <node id="4">
    <child attr="boringValue"/>
    <predecessors/>
  </node>
  <node id="5">
    <child attr="boringValue"/>
    <predecessors>
      <node id="4">
        <child attr="boringValue"/>
      </node>
    </predecessors>
  </node>
  <node id="6">
    <child attr="boringValue"/>
    <predecessors>
      <node id="4">
        <child attr="boringValue"/>
      </node>
      <node id="5">
        <child attr="boringValue"/>
      </node>
    </predecessors>
  </node>
</xml>
```

Note, the reason I use `[1]` in `preceding-sibling::node[child/@attr='valueOfInterest'][1]` is because the order of the nodeset is reversed by `preceding-sibling` [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497197/how-to-get-the-real-node-order-from-xpath-expression-java/5497298#5497298).

If you have XPath 2.0, you can use the `intersect` operator

```
  <predecessors>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$set1 intersect $set2"/>
  </predecessors>
```

This produces the same result.

Answer (score 3):

**This transformation copies exactly the wanted nodes**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match=
 "node[not(child/attr='valueOfInterest')]">

 <xsl:variable name="vFollowing" select=
 "preceding-sibling::node
          [child/@attr='valueOfInterest'][1]
            /following-sibling::node"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vPreceding" select=
  "preceding-sibling::node"/>

  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "$vFollowing[count(. | $vPreceding)
              =
               count($vPreceding)
              ]
  "/>
======================
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (based on the provided XML fragment and wrapping it in a top element to make it a well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
    <node id="1">
        <child attr="valueOfInterest"/>
    </node>
    <node id="2">
        <child attr="boringValue"/>
    </node>...
    <node id="3">
        <child attr="valueOfInterest"/>
    </node>
    <node id="4">
        <child attr="boringValue"/>
    </node>
    <node id="5">
        <child attr="boringValue"/>
    </node>
    <node id="6">
        <child attr="boringValue"/>
    </node>...
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
======================

======================
 <node id="2">
   <child attr="boringValue"/>
</node>
======================

======================
 <node id="4">
   <child attr="boringValue"/>
</node>
======================
 <node id="4">
   <child attr="boringValue"/>
</node>
<node id="5">
   <child attr="boringValue"/>
</node>
======================
```

**Explanation**:

1. Here we use the well-known *Kayessian* formula (discovered by the SO user @Michael Kay) for the intersection of two node-sets `$ns1` and `$ns2`:

   ns1[count(.|$ns2) = count($ns2)]
2. We simply substitute `$vFollowing` and `$vPreceding` for `$ns1` and `$ns2` in the above formula.

`$vFollowing is defined to contain exactly all the following sibling elements named`node`of the nearest`node` that satisfies the condition (to be interesting).

`$vPreceding` is the set of all `node` elements that are preceding siblings of the current (matched) node.

.3. Their intersection is exactly the wanted node-set.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it in XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:variable name="prevVOI"
      select="(preceding-sibling::node[child/@attr = 'valueOfInterest'])[last()]" />
<xsl:variable name="prevNodesAfterVOI"
      select="preceding-sibling::node[. >> $prevVOI]" />
```

Comment: Do note you need to select the first matched preceding sibling to compare against a single node, and make the second instruction works correctly.

Comment: @empo: thanks, you're entirely right. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: May be more intuitive `preceding-sibling::node[child/@attr = 'valueOfInterest'][1]` :))

Comment: @empo: in a way, I agree; but for me it's always hard to remember when the `[1]` is bound closely enough to the reverse axis so that `[1]` actually means last in document order; and when it isn't. But if I use `(...)[last()]` then I know for sure that I'm selecting the last in document order.